# Iam getting iTunes store operation failed error when validating the app

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

[image]

I am getting this error when validating app with itunes connect please help me to fix this
Thanks

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your code.

Comment: which code you need? this is my first app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution
this error happend because i was using old version of google plus sdk
i updated the sdk now its fixed